# Unable to create a new asset in version one using the Java API

Tags: java, versionone

Hi I am facing issue while trying to develop an automation using Version One Java SDK and I am not able to create new items under the project. The code fails with the following exception everytime:

```
com.versionone.apiclient.exceptions.APIException: Error processing response
    at com.versionone.apiclient.Services.save(Services.java:337)
    at com.versionone.apiclient.Services.save(Services.java:290)
    at yia.vone.connect.YodV1Connector.createPortfolioItem(YodV1Connector.java:46)
    at yia.vone.connect.YodV1Connector.main(YodV1Connector.java:55)
Caused by: com.versionone.apiclient.exceptions.OidException: Invalid OID token: 
    at com.versionone.Oid.fromToken(Oid.java:184)
    at com.versionone.apiclient.Services.getOid(Services.java:252)
    at com.versionone.apiclient.Services.parseSaveAssetNode(Services.java:552)
    at com.versionone.apiclient.Services.save(Services.java:335)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.versionone.Oid.fromToken(Oid.java:177)
    ... 6 more
```

Code is as follows:

```
public static void createPortfolioItem(V1Connector connector) throws V1Exception {
    IServices services = new Services(connector);
    Oid projectId = services.getOid("Scope:244424");
    System.out.println(projectId.getToken());

    IAssetType epicType = services.getMeta().getAssetType("Epic");
    System.out.println(epicType.getToken());

    Asset newItem = services.createNew(epicType, projectId);
    System.out.println(newItem.getOid().getToken());

    IAttributeDefinition nameAttribute = epicType.getAttributeDefinition("Name");
    newItem.setAttributeValue(nameAttribute, "Internal Test X");

    // Exception occurs here
    services.save(newItem);

    System.out.println(newItem.getOid().getToken());
    System.out.println(newItem.getAttribute(
        epicType.getAttributeDefinition("Scope")).getValue());
    System.out.println(newItem.getAttribute(nameAttribute).getValue());
}
```

The exception occurs on the line:

```
services.save(newItem);
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that your *OID* in `Oid projectId = services.getOid("Scope:244424");` is correct? Because it says `Caused by: com.versionone.apiclient.exceptions.OidException: Invalid OID token`.

Comment: Thank you for asking,Initially I too thought that was the problem, but yes that is correct.